# mysqli code, getting error as Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given & null is given

Tags: php, mysqli

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/fewatrai/public_html/includes/function.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/fewatrai/public_html/includes/function.php on line 7

my code is:
**function.php**

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; 
function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?'){ 
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $query);
.....
....
?>
```

and
connect.php

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$user= "root";
$pass= "";
$db= "fewa";
$err1 = "Couldn't connect db, try again ";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die($err1);
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($conn, $db);
?>
```

i have pagination page, where items are displayed:
categoy.php

```
<?php 
 include_once ('includes/function.php');
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
$limit = 3;
$startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
//to make pagination
 $sql = "items where subcat2_id='$subcat2_id'";
 //show records
 $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM {$sql} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
......
 <?php }?>
 <?php  echo pagination($sql,$limit,$page,"?subcat2_id=".$subcat2_id."&"); ?>
```

Comment: Check for an error prior to calling `mysqli_fetch_array()`, likely your `$query` variable is malformed.

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php for parameter in mysqli_query function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `mysqli_query()` requires two parameters. The first being an open mysql connection resource (the result of `mysql_connect()`). In your case `$conn` needs to be the first parameter.

Eg:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}");
```

You'll need to make `$conn` one of the parameters of `pagination()` in order for it to be available in the function.

Also, you are connected using `MySQLi` the OOP version, not procedural. This means you should you're better off using `$conn->query()` not `mysqli_query($conn)`

Edit:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

...

```
function pagination(mysqli $conn, $query, $per_page = 10, $page = 1, $url = '?'){ 
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Do stuff
    }
    ...
}
```

...

```
<?php echo pagination($conn, $sql,$limit,$page,"?subcat2_id=".$subcat2_id."&"); ?>
```

Comment: You need to stop using the `mysqli_` functions, instead use the `mysqli` class and member functions. More info can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Comment: Thank you so much Ian, you saved me.It worked as expected. Thank you again.